# populating the JSON data from spring mvc to d3 chart using request body

Tags: json, spring-mvc, d3.js

I'm tyring to poplulate the data from the server as json into d3 to generate chart.

In server side I generated the JSON object using spring as below, by just populating the data in hashmap and sending the responce through spring responce body.

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting1")
    @ResponseBody
    public LinkedHashMap<String, String> greeting1(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name,
            Model model) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> values = data.populateData();
        model.addAttribute("name", values);
        return values;
    }
```

In client side I'm populating the data to a div and trying to inject into d3 as below (but dosen't work).

**case 1:**

```
 var test_data=d3.select("body").selectAll("test_data");
    data=test_data.html;
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

The above code is requiring JSON as in the following format.

**case 2:**

```
   var data = [{x:0,y:0.5},{x:0.1,y:0.8},{x:0.2,y:1.1},{x:1.3,y:1.5},{x:0.4,y:2.5},{x:0.5,y:3.4},{x:0.6,y:4.3}];
       x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
       y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }));
```

How shall I generate the JSON in the format specified  from the server side ( as in case 2) ?

How shall i capture the div test_data in d3 ?

complete js code for d3 as below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Getting Started: Serving Web Content</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<style>
.axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.dot {
    fill: #fff;
    stroke: #000;
}
</style>

<script src="./d3.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
<script src="./data.tsv"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      sendAjax();
    });

    function sendAjax() {

    $.ajax({ 
        url: "/greeting1", 
        type: 'GET', 
       /* dataType: 'json', 
        data: "{\"name\":\"hmkcode\",\"id\":2}", 
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',*/
        success: function(data) { 
           //alert(data);
           $('#test_data').html(data);
           //alert($('#test_data').html);
           callChart();
        },
        error:function(data,status,er) { 
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
        }
    });
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
    <p th:text="'Hello, ' + ${name} + '!'" />
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="test_data"></div>
    <script>

function callChart()
{

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([2 / 3, 1]) // D3 3.x tension is buggy!
    .range(["brown", "steelblue"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
 // if (error) throw error;

    //var test_data=d3.select("body").selectAll("test_data");
    //data=test_data.html;
    var data = [{x:0,y:0.5},{x:0.1,y:0.8},{x:0.2,y:1.1},{x:1.3,y:1.5},{x:0.4,y:2.5},{x:0.5,y:3.4},{x:0.6,y:4.3}];
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }));
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".line")
      .data(z.ticks(6))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line.tension(d)(data); })
      .style("stroke", z);

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("r", 3.5);
//});

function type(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}


}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you're selecting by ID, it has to be `selectAll("#test_data");`. Consider changing for `select`, since IDs are unique. Besides that, `html` as a getter has parentheses: `html()`.

Comment: ok thanks i'll correct it, you mean  var test_data=d3.selectAll("test_data"); right.

Comment: Yes. It should be `var test_data = d3.select("#test_data");` and `data = test_data.html();`.

Comment: ok thnks i'll correct that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved by using gson for constructing the Json and the solution provided by @Gerardo Furtado for fetching the div through d3.

```
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
            Model model) {
        LinkedList<Data.Temp> values = data.populateData();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String output=gson.toJson(values);
        model.addAttribute("name",output );
        return "greeting";
    }

function callChart()
{

    var margin = {top: 40, right: 40, bottom: 40, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 1])
    .range([height, 0]);

var z = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([2 / 3, 1]) // D3 3.x tension is buggy!
    .range(["brown", "steelblue"]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("cardinal")
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//d3.tsv("data.tsv", type, function(error, data) {
 // if (error) throw error;

    //var test_data=d3.select("body").selectAll("test_data");
    //data=test_data.html;
    var test_data = d3.select("#test_data"); 
    var data = JSON.parse(test_data.text());
    x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.y; }));
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);

  svg.selectAll(".line")
      .data(z.ticks(6))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", function(d) { return line.tension(d)(data); })
      .style("stroke", z);

  svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.x); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("r", 3.5);
//});

function type(d) {
  d.x = +d.x;
  d.y = +d.y;
  return d;
}


}
```